# how to save checkbox values into database field using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

Im trying to store  all the inputs from the checkboxes to the database using Laravel. the checkbox values should be stored into database separated by a comma. how to do it? and how to write the controller method

#### 4. How would you describe your style? Check all that apply

```
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Casual">Casual</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="City/Urban">City/Urban</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Country/Cottage Chic">Country/Cottage Chic</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Eclectic">Eclectic</label></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

define `name` attribute in your input element

(eg: `<input type="checkbox" name="style" value="casual">`)

then in your controller:

`$style = implode( Input::get('style',[]) );`

then save it in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
    <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Casual">Casual</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="style[]"value="City/Urban">City/Urban</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Country/Cottage Chic">Country/Cottage Chic</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Eclectic">Eclectic</label></div>
```

Controller:

```
$style = implode(',', Input::get('style'));
$data = array('style',$style);
DB::table($table_name)->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
$request["elective_status"] = ($request["elective_status"] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
$data->fill($request->all())->save();
```